# SQL agrupar registros por horário

Tags: sql, sintaxe

Tenho uma tabela no MySQL que armazena eventos por horário com a seguinte estrutura:

> id / num_veh / time

Gostaria de criar uma consulta SQL que retornasse os eventos em grupos por faixa de horário . Por exemplo:

> Das 01:00 às 06:00 - 500 itens / Das 07:00 às 12:00 - 800 itens

Pesquisei bastante a esse respeito e acredito que estou bem próximo com o seguinte SQL:

```
    SELECT grupos, SUM(num_veh) as quantidade
FROM (
     SELECT( CASE
         WHEN DATE_FORMAT(time, '%H:%i:%s') > '00:00' 
         && DATE_FORMAT(time, '%H:%i:%s') < '06:00' THEN '00h às 06h'
         WHEN DATE_FORMAT(time, '%H:%i:%s') > '06:00' 
         && DATE_FORMAT(time, '%H:%i:%s') < '12:00' THEN '06h às 12h'
         ELSE 0 END)
     as grupos
     FROM tb_events
     ) as acessos
GROUP BY grupos
ORDER BY quantidade;
```

Porém, não está funcionando e retorna o erro:

> Coluna 'num_veh' desconhecida em 'field list'

Alguém sabe como corrigir este problema? Ou então sabe me dizer como eu poderia fazer diferente para encontrar um solução?

Comment: Você está fazendo select a colunas que não existem segundo o código que postou. Aliás nem vejo onde está a coluna num_veh.

Comment: Não há nada que não tenha colocado na sua query? É que o campo `num_veh` não existe na consulta.

Comment: Provavelmente o erro não se refere a esta query.

Comment: Desculpe, tentei simplificar o contexto da minha aplicação substituindo o num_veh por qtd.

Answer (score 0):

Faltou informar a coluna "num_veh" em seu sub-select

```
   SELECT grupos, SUM(num_veh) as quantidade
    FROM (
         SELECT num_veh, 
             ( CASE
             WHEN DATE_FORMAT(time, '%H:%i:%s') > '00:00' 
             && DATE_FORMAT(time, '%H:%i:%s') < '06:00' THEN '00h às 06h'
             WHEN DATE_FORMAT(time, '%H:%i:%s') > '06:00' 
             && DATE_FORMAT(time, '%H:%i:%s') < '12:00' THEN '06h às 12h'
             ELSE 0 END)
         as grupos
         FROM tb_events
         ) as acessos
    GROUP BY grupos
    ORDER BY quantidade;
```